# Express Types for HTTP2

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, http2

I'd like to leverage the `http2` module in Node 10 in conjunction with Express and TypeScript (2.8.x).

In can instantiate a server with something like:

```
import * as http2 from "http2";

let server = http2.createServer({}, app).listen(8080);
```

The problem is that I'll get a type error for `app`.  The issue is that `http2.createServer` wants the second argument to be of type:

```
(request: http2.Http2ServerRequest, response: http2.Http2ServerResponse) => void
```

The problem is that according to `@types/express`, the type of `app` is ([apparently](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L844)):

```
(req: Request | http.IncomingMessage, res: Response | http.ServerResponse): any
```

Now I can do an ugly cast like this:

```
import * as http2 from "http2";

let server = http2.createServer({}, (app as any) as ((request: http2.Http2ServerRequest, response: http2.Http2ServerResponse) => void)).listen(8080);
```

But the issue is really later when I write my Express handlers, it seems that I would have to write them as:

```
(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  let req2 = (req as any) as http2.Http2ServerRequest;
  let res2 = (res as any) as http2.Http2ServerResponse;
  ...
}
```

...in order to access all the `http2` functionality like push, no?

So I'm having to do these casts on both ends.  Now, if there were a `@types/express-http2` that had all the Express typings but assuming an underlying core of `http2`, then none of this would be necessarily I would think.  But I couldn't find such a thing.

I recognize this is a tricky typing problem because all the Express typings, as far as I can tell, are written with the assumption of `http` as the underlying service layer.  As I understand it, Express itself works fine with `http2`, but the issue is that the typings don't work cleanly.

Am I missing something?

P.S. - I would prefer Express, but if there is another Node based web framework that supports this combination of `http2` and TypeScript better, I could consider that as well.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. Internally `express` uses the `http` module.

You could cast it as you are doing, but you are somewhat doing a hack by casting it to `any` then again to `http2.Http2ServerRequest` when ultimately it is **not** a `http2.Http2ServerRequest`.

There is an open PR for `http2` support: https://github.com/expressjs/express/pull/3390

Answer (score 0):

One approach I found was to use `fastify`.  They don't exactly have native support for `http2`, but they allow access to the underlying raw request object.  So when you enable `http2` support, accessing that `raw` element of the `fastify` request hands you back a `http2.Http2ServerRequest`.

The best part, from a TypeScript perspective, is that they have defined the types such that when you pass the configuration options into `fastify`, it recognizes when the `http2` flag is set and adjusts the return type.  In this way, it is completely type safe (not casts to `any` and back are required).

For now, `fastify` seems to be a reasonable way to go if you want `http2` and type safety.  I haven't used it in production though, so I cannot vouch for its stability or performance.